# Dictionary displaying last element

Tags: ios, swift

Displaying a label text using dictionary values but I'm facing some issues. The last value of dictionary is replacing all 10 values.

My code is here:

```swift
var myListArrayDict = [String:String]()
for (item,itreated) in resultList.enumerated() {
    print("enumurated  \(item) \(itreated)")

    for itro in itreated {
        myListArrayDict[itro.key] = itro.value

        print("newItemList \(newItem)")

        let item = myListArrayDict[element.FieldName] ?? ""
        label.text = item
    }
}
```

The following image shows the dictionary value of the last element replacing all rows.

[image: Results]

[Original image of code snippet is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OYFy.jpg)

Comment: please share the code as well

Comment: Yeah sure! Ill share the code

Comment: please share the code in the question, not via a link. Thank you

Comment: As @NaqeebAhmed requested, please paste your source code as text into your question (ie.  not a link to an image of the source).  You can mark the beginning with three back-ticks followed by `swift` and the end with three back-ticks to mark it as a swift code block.

Comment: I reformatted your code and made image of the results display directly in your question.   It would be helpful if you were to include the declaration of `resultList`.  I suspect that `itro.key` is repeated, and thus overwrites the same entry in `myListArrayDict `

Comment: @ChipJarred can you share the code

Comment: @Nirmal, I don't know what you mean.  When I said I reformatted your code, I meant that I edited your question to reformat the code in it.  Originally it had a *lot* of vertical white space and deep indentations that made it hard to read on Stack Overflow.   I did not change your actual code, just removed blank lines and shrank indentations to 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You are running the same function (for block) for each row so you are iterating the whole dictionary every time and the result is that you print in the label always the last value.

Comment: I agree this is the correct answer.  If you have the time and inclination to improve it a bit, you could clarify that OP needs to extract only the data from the `resultsList` for the current cell... or I guess you could just let this comment be that clarification.

Comment: can i have correct code

Comment: @Nirmal, your code refers to `resultsList`, which is defined outside of the function and not included in the code you provided, so it would be difficult for someone to provide compilable correct code.

Comment: @Nirmal, your function is being called once for each cell, yet each time you iterate through your entire `resultsList`, which of course, means on every cell the last data you get is the last that item in `resultsList`.  Instead of looping, you need to get just the data for the cell corresponding to `cellForRowAt` (which isn't shown in your pasted code, but is visible in the image of the code).

Comment: any one say how to create a dictionary of string,array